# EclipseLink JPA CriteriaBuilder generated invalid SQL Syntax

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink, criteria-api

I have two objects, both defined as entities, one containing the other as follows:

```
@Entity
public class TestC 
{
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @ManyToOne (cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE} )
    TestD d;
} 

@Entity
public class TestD 
{
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    String moo;
}
```

The entities are persisted:

```
TestC c2 = new TestC();
TestD d2 = new TestD();
d2.moo = "d2";
c2.d = d2;
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(d2);
em.persist(c2);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

I am trying to query for TestC objects with an instance of TestD:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<TestC> query = builder.createQuery(TestC.class);
Root<TestC> from = query.from(TestC.class);

ParameterExpression<TestD> pe = builder.parameter(TestD.class);

query.where(builder.equal(pe, from.<TestD>get("d")));

TestC found = em.createQuery(query)
    .setParameter(pe, d2)
    .getSingleResult();
```

But EclipseLink kicks out the following error when running the query (note the SQL is invalid near "(? = )", there is no column name for the TestD object):

```
Exception in thread "main" Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT t1.ID, t1.D_ID FROM TESTD t0, TESTC t1 WHERE ((? = ) AND (t0.ID = t1.D_ID))
bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=TestC sql="SELECT t1.ID, t1.D_ID FROM TESTD t0, TESTC t1 WHERE ((? = ) AND (t0.ID = t1.D_ID))")
```

Am I building the query wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Even when the objects implement Serializable I still get a SQL syntax error (I'm using MySQL): Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND (t0.ID = t1.D_ID))' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

It is not documented in the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#equal%28javax.persistence.criteria.Expression,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Expression%29), but ParameterExpression should be second argument. Order follows same logic as *equal(Expression x, java.lang.Object y)*. Additionally you need *.select*. EclipseLink (at least 2.3.0) works also without, but according specification leaving select/multiselect out is not portable:

> *Portable applications should use the select or multiselect method to
>   specify the query’s selection list. Applications that do not use one
>   of these methods will not be portable.*

After those changes, correct approach is:

```
CriteriaQuery<TestC> query = builder.createQuery(TestC.class);
Root<TestC> from = query.from(TestC.class);

ParameterExpression<TestD> pe = builder.parameter(TestD.class);
query.select(from)
     .where(builder.equal(from.<TestD>get("d"), pe));

TestC found = em.createQuery(query)
                .setParameter(pe, d)
                .getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Thank you!! Switching the parameter order to which() fixed the issue (never even considered that). Interestingly Hibernate worked with the parameters the wrong way round.

Comment: That's good. For me it looks that Hibernate is right, because this order is not documented.